# Outlook HTML Signature Wrapping in Gmail on Mobile Devices

Tags: html, css, outlook, gmail, signature

I have been tasked with implementing our companies new email HTML signature layout. However I'm having difficulty getting my HTML signature (which originates from Microsoft Outlook) from ***not*** wrapping in gmail on mobile devices. I've used strictly inline style tags and most elements already contain *white-space: nowrap*, so I'm not sure why it continues to wrap on the longer elements (in gmail on a mobile device), but no where else.

Am I missing something? Is there a specific inline style gmail uses to prevent wrapping? Or is there a physical width limit that is forced on the native gmail android app?

Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

(I'm implementing this signature by copying the below .htm file into %appdata%/microsoft/signatures)

Below is my html code with similar sized sample context code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body link="#f68f1e" vlink="#f68f1e" alink="#f68f1e">
<br />
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">
<font style="line-height: 1.25; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;"><b>John Smith Jr</b></font><br />
<font style="line-height: 1.25; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">Very Long Job Title That Is Very Descriptive With Extra Details</font><br />
<font style="line-height: 1.25; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">*Licensed in CA</font><br />
</font>
<br />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; white-space: nowrap;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/neH8Pg2.png" border="0" width="171" height="105"></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">
<font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap;">Office</font><font style="line-height: 0.5; letter-spacing: 5px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</font><font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; white-space: nowrap;">111.111.1111</font><font style="line-height: 0.5; letter-spacing: 5px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</font><font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap;">Ext.</font><font style="line-height: 0.5; letter-spacing: 6px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</font><font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; white-space: nowrap;">1111</font><br/>
<font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap;">Direct</font><font style="line-height: 0.5; letter-spacing: 4px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</font><font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; white-space: nowrap;">111.111.1111</font><font style="line-height: 0.5; letter-spacing: 5px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</font><font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap;">Cell</font><font style="line-height: 0.5; letter-spacing: 5px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</font><font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; white-space: nowrap;">111.111.1111</font><br/>
<font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap;">Fax</font><font style="line-height: 0.5; letter-spacing: 19px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</font><font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; white-space: nowrap;">111.111.1111</font><br />
<br />
<font style="line-height: 1.25; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; white-space: nowrap;">Big Bird Bird, Inc.</font><br />
<font style="line-height: 1.25; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; white-space: nowrap;">1111 Big Bird Street Dr, Ste 11, BigBirdState, CA, 99999</font><br />
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com" style="line-height: 1.25; text-decoration: none; white-space: nowrap;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/OZ5SuTS.png" border="0" height="15" width="15"></a>&nbsp;</font>
<font style="line-height: 1.25; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color:#f68f1e; white-space: nowrap;"><a href="http://www.notarealurl.com" style="text-decoration: none;">www.notarealurl.com</a></font>
<font style="line-height: 1.25; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color:#0073b2; white-space: nowrap;">|</font>
<font style="line-height: 1.25; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color:#f68f1e; white-space: nowrap;"><a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration: none;">map</a></font>
<font style="line-height: 1.25; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color:#0073b2; white-space: nowrap;">|</font>
<font style="line-height: 1.25; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color:#f68f1e; white-space: nowrap;"><a href="mailto:jsmithjr@emailaddress.com" style="text-decoration: none; white-space: nowrap;">email</a></font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```