# How do I prevent an html signature from wrapping in Gmail for Android?

Tags: android, html, css, outlook-2010

I need to finalize a company-wide signature form and want to make sure it looks good on most devices. The code below works well in Outlook (PC, Mac, iPhone, Android), Yahoo (iPhone, Android), and Gmail on iPhone. However, the lines in the address still wrap on Gmail for Android.

I have tried several suggested hacks I found for Gmail-specific problems that sounded similar, but with no success or observable change:

- Adding `!important` to the `white-space: nowrap` property
- Using an inline style for the `white-space: nowrap` (also tried this with `!important`)
- Adding a style for `* {-webkit-text-size-adjust: none}`
- Adding an unbroken string of text with `white-space: none` and `display: none`

Does anyone know of a workaround for Gmail on Android to keep it from wrapping? Or a better solution? Surely other companies have developed signatures that look good on all platforms :)

Here is my current code (no hacks applied):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      <!--
        table {
          border: none;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
        }
        p {
          line-height: 1.4;
          font-size: 9.0pt;
          font-family: Arial, sans serif;
          letter-spacing: .1pt;
          color: black;
        }
        p.emphasis
        {
          font-weight: bold;
          margin-bottom: 1.0em;
        }
        span.name {
          color: #ED1C24;
        }
        .content {
      padding-left: 5px;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
      -->
    </style>
  </head>
   <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0eTy.gif" alt="Company Logo" width="325" height="81"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="content">
          <p class="emphasis"><span class="name">John Doe</span> |
            Chief Awesomizer<br/>
            Big Ideas Department</p>
          <p>a | 1234 Big Long Street Name S-11 Anytown, USA 55555<br/>
            o | 333.123.4567 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;f | 333.000.0000 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;m | these lines are wrapping on Gmail for Android!<br/>
            e | <a href="mailto:fakeemailaddress@myexampledomain.com">fakeemailaddress@myexampledomain.com</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;w | <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a><br/>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Screenshot of Desired Rendering:** [iPhone 6S and elsewhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cvXN.png)

**Screenshot of Gmail on Android:** [Galaxy 3, also observed on Galaxy 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Q3M.png)

I am creating these signatures in Microsoft Outlook 2010 (our company standard--any proposed solution must work *sending* from Outlook to be accepted) by rendering the html in IE 11, selecting all, and pasting it into the Edit Signature window (`new E-mail Message` -> `Signature Dropdown` -> `Signatures...` -> `New` -> `Edit Signature`). *Note that pasting from Chrome did not bring over the image correctly.*

Comment: using `<style>` in html mail is risky, try using inline styles

Comment: As I mentioned, I did try an inline style for the white-space: nowrap, but with no luck. I will try converting the whole thing to use inline styles but it seems like other style rules are being applied as expected (e.g. the bold font)

Comment: There are lists of supported css by gmail (I don't have a link but you can probably [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=supported+css+by+gmail)), maybe the rule you are using is not supported.

Comment: Just found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21715090/5003971), but it has no answers--the OP there had used only inline styles. (Sorry I've been covered up with higher priority stuff so haven't had a chance yet to try inlining mine)

Comment: List of supported css features by email client (according to mailchimp): http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/

Comment: Well, I have since moved on to other things--we ended up "solving" this by reducing the font size for the address lines to make it less likely to wrap. Frustrating though, especially since according to the link @RC. posted `white-space` should be supported by all clients.